# Move an image right and down on first scroll,right and up on second scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var totalHeight = 0;

$(".scroll-section").each(function(){
    totalHeight += $(this).height();
});


$(".site-content").scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(".site-content").scrollTop();

    var movePos = (scrollTop / totalHeight) * 100;
    movePos = movePos + 100;
    console.log(movePos);
    $(".page-fixed").css("background-size", `${movePos}% 100%`)

});
```

I tried margin, does not work
Doing this for webflow so yeah... Would need to get it webflow compatible as well